# Is it possible to implement a contains check between 2 comma separated list (obtained by group_concat) in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

Consider the following table (sample table, these are not the exact values in the table)

```
+-----+--------+--------+
| uid | pqid   | rqid   |
+-----+--------+--------+
|   1 | 1,2,3  | 1,3    |
|   2 | 1,2    | 2,3    |
|   3 | 2      | 2,3    |
|   4 | 2,3    | 3      |
|   5 | 1,3    | 1,3    |
+-----+--------+--------+
```

I am trying to select rows, which have `rqid` contained in `pqid`. By 'contains' I mean, all the comma separated ids in `rqid` should be present in the comma separated list in `pqid`.
In the above example row, we need to select `uid` 1, 4 and 5.

Is that something doable in mysql? If so can somebody help out?

PS:

1. This values of `pqid` and `rqid` are generated by `group_concat`
2. The ids in the columns will be sorted, distinct and not null (if this
   helps)

Comment: Never store multiple values in a single column. You need to change your table design.

Comment: There is something called `FIND_IN_SET`, but this would only work if you had _single_ values in `rqid`, not a CSV list of them.  And even then, you should avoid storing CSV data in your table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for pointing out `FIND_IN_SET`, as you mentioned it works for one value only.

Comment: If you want to get anywhere here, you should go back to the step before you generated this CSV table.  Is there some way you could generate a table where `rqid` has only one value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes Sir, that would be possible (I am assuming here that, there will be multiple rows but only 1 value in `rqid` per row but other values duplicated)

Comment: I refuse to consider such a table. I reject the premise the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a like check right above the obtained result set like this:

```
select * from (
 //QUERY THAT brings grouped result
) alias where alias.pqid like '%2,3,4%' or alias.rqid like '%1,2%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I nice hideous bit of SQL to do it for you (coping with up to 1000 items in the comma separated list in rqid). The main thing this shows is that it would be better to normalise your database.

```
SELECT a.uid, a.pqid, a.rqid
FROM some_table a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT uid, pqid, rqid, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(rqid, ',', hundreds.acnt * 100 + tens.acnt * 10 + units.acnt + 1), ',', -1) as a_rqid
    FROM some_table
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT 1 acnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0
    ) units
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT 1 acnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0
    ) tens
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT 1 acnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0
    ) hundreds
) sub0
ON a.uid = sub0.uid
AND FIND_IN_SET(sub0.a_rqid, a.pqid)
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT uid, pqid, rqid, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(rqid, ',', hundreds.acnt * 100 + tens.acnt * 10 + units.acnt + 1), ',', -1) as a_rqid
    FROM some_table
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT 1 acnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0
    ) units
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT 1 acnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0
    ) tens
    CROSS JOIN
    (
        SELECT 1 acnt UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0
    ) hundreds
) sub1
ON a.uid = sub1.uid
GROUP BY a.uid, a.pqid, a.rqid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT sub0.a_rqid) = COUNT(DISTINCT sub1.a_rqid)
```